# Error when accessing a control's data of one form in another form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have two forms in my application. In my **Form1** I have a list view having some items. When I double click on a row, I should get a pop-up window allowing me edit the row values. For this I used doubleclick event. Now for the pop-up window I created new form- **Form2**. I have made the listview as internal in Form1, so as to access the selected rows values in my form2. In form2 load I am retrieving the values of selected row to display in textboxes but this gives me error. This is my code:

```
   //this is in form1
   private void bufferedListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 obj = new form2();
        obj.ShowDialog();
    }

   //in form2
   Form1 o = new Form1();
   private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_editname.Text = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        txt_editno.Text = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    }
```

The error that I get is: `InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: oh why is that so? Am I not just creating an object for form1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass needed data in constructor of form2

```
public form2(string text1, string text2)
{
   //work with values
}
```

And change calling code to this:

```
private void bufferedListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 obj = new form2(bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
       bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
    obj.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I have a new problem now. I used your way and that worked. But problem is the next time I click a row the error is repeated. Its because I am not discarding the object everytime. So I added this: `obj = null;
 GC.Collect();` But still there is a typical problem, after few clicks, the error is again repeated. Why is it happening?

Comment: When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close button (the button with an X at the upper-right corner of the form) causes the form to be hidden

Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

See remarks there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Comment: Yes I did give a button to cancel and wrote `this.Dispose();` in it. I click in listview, form2 opens then I close using cancel button. I do it 3-4 times then I get the error

Comment: For the clarification, what exactly error you're getting?

And there is Close() method of the form, it should do a proper closing form.

Comment: ERROR: `(ArgumentOutOfRangeException): InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: More info: my listview is regularly updated using a timer of 1000 milliseconds. Is there anything it got to do?

Comment: This is not error related with forms, it's saying to you that you are trying to access some array out of its bounds. form2 obj = new form2(bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
       bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
This code containing direct calls to SelectedItems at index 0, but if there is no selected items this exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 o = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_editname.Text = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    txt_editno.Text = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

you should retrieve the instance of Form1 which is already created, not a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
    //this is in form1
    private void bufferedListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 obj = new form2
                        {
                            Name = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
                            No = o.bufferedListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text,
                        };
        obj.ShowDialog();
    }

    //in form2
    public String Name;
    public String No;
    Form1 o = new Form1();
    private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_editname.Text = Name;
        txt_editno.Text = No;
    }
```